# mysql - PHP select from table does not work

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to get the FirstName value based on the email and password provided by the user. But for some reason the code I have does not return anything. Can anybody help?

```
$sql_result = "SELECT FirstName FROM $tbl_name WHERE Email='$email' and Password='$mypassword' limit 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql_result);
$value = mysql_fetch_object($res);

$_SESSION['name']=$value['FirstName'];
```

I have also tried the code below but that didn't work either.

```
 $_SESSION['name']=$value->FirstName;
```

Comment: are u sure your query is executing ? first use mysql_error() to see whats going on.

Comment: Did you use session_start() at the top of the script? It would be really useful to see more of the code here. And Abhik's comment is right on.

Comment: @larsAnders Yes I do have session_start() at the top of the code. And Abhik I did put mysql_error() and got these:

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/u342178811/public_html/checklogin.php on line 54 Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/u342178811/public_html/checklogin.php on line 55

Comment: object ?? can u please post the full code.. are u mixing mysqli object and mysql_

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thanks a lot for your help my friend. Yes, apparently, I got them mixed up.

Comment: great you found out it will be easy for u to fix now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = mysql_fetch_object($res);
                     ^^^^^^^---- fetching an object

$_SESSION['name']=$value['FirstName'];
                   ^^^^^^^^^---treating it like an array
```

Try `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead, so your `$value` really is an array, or use `$value->FirstName` and use it as the object it really is.

Comment: Psst... The OP mentions using `$_SESSION['name']=$value->FirstName;`